# Java: How Executors relate to Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So in Java concurrency, there is the concept of a *task* which is really any implementing `Runnable` or `Callable` (and, more specifically, the overridden `run()` or `call()` method of that interface).

I'm having a tough time understanding the relationship between:

- A task (`Runnable`/`Callable`); and
- An `ExecutorService` the task is submitted to; and
- An underlying, concurrent work queue or list structure used by the `ExecutorService`

I *believe* the relationship is something of the following:

- You, the developer, must select which `ExecutorService` and work structure best suits the task at hand
- You initialize the `ExecutorService` (say, as a `ScheduledThreadPool`) with the underlying structure to use (say, an `ArrayBlockingQueue`) (if so, **how?!?!**)
- You submit your task to the `ExecutorService` which then uses its threading/pooling strategy to populate the given structure (ABQ or otherwise) with copies of the task
- Each spawned/pooled thread now pulls copies of the task off of the work structure and executes it

First off, please correct/clarify any of the above assumptions if I am off-base on any of them!

Second, if the task is simply *copied*/replicated over and over again inside the underlying work structure (e.g., identical copies in each index of a list), then how do you ever decompose a big problem down into smaller (concurrent) ones? In other words, if the task simply does steps A - Z, and you have an ABQ with 1,000 of those tasks, then won't each thread just do A - Z as well? How do you say "some threads should work on A - G, while other threads should work on H, and yet other threads should work on I - Z", etc.?

For this second one I might need a code example to visualize how it all comes together. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though by no means exhaustive, I would highly recommend reading the [Java documentation for ThreadedPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). There is some information in it I think you will find helpful in understanding these concepts.

Comment: Tasks themselves are not copied. Only references to the tasks are floating around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last assumption is not quite right. The `ExecutorService` does not pull copies of the task. The program must supply all tasks individually to be performed by the `ExecutorService`. When a task has finished, the next task in the queue is executed.

An `ExecutorService` is an interface for working with a thread pool. You generally have multiple tasks to be executed on the pool, and each operates on a different part of the problem. As the developer, you must specify which parts of the problem each task should work on when creating it, before sending it to the `ExecutorService`. The results of each task (assuming they are working on a common problem) should be added to a `BlockingQueue` or other concurrent collection, where another thread may use the results or wait for all tasks to finish.

Here is an article you may want to read about how to use an `ExecutorService`: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools

Update: A common use of the `ExecutorService` is to implement the producer/consumer pattern. Here is an example I quickly threw together to get you started--it is intended for demonstration purposes only, as some details and concerns have been omitted for simplicity. The thread pool contains multiple producer threads and one consumer thread. The job being performed is to sum the numbers from 0...N. Each producer thread sums a smaller interval of numbers, and publishes the result to the `BlockingQueue`. The consumer thread processes each result added to the `BlockingQueue`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NumberCounter {

    private final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(100);

    public void startCounter(int max, int workers) {
        // Create multiple tasks to add numbers. Each task submits the result
        // to the queue.
        int increment = max / workers;
        for (int worker = 0; worker < workers; worker++) {
            Runnable task = createProducer(worker * increment, (worker + 1) * increment);
            pool.execute(task);
        }

        // Create one more task that will consume the numbers, adding them up
        // and printing the results.
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            int sum = 0;

            while (true) {
                try {
                Integer result = queue.take();
                sum += result;
                System.out.println("New sum is " + sum);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable createProducer(final int start, final int stop) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
            System.out.println("Worker started counting from " + start + " to " + stop);
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = start; i < stop; i++) {
                count += i;
                }
                queue.add(count);
            }

        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        NumberCounter counter = new NumberCounter();
        counter.startCounter(10000, 5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response @Nate - I'm still not seeing the "forest through the trees", though. Any chance you can whip up a small snippet that shows a task being chomped up into a few smaller tasks, and each smaller task being sent to its own `ExecutorService` with its own work queue/structure? I think my problem lies in how to figure out what to submit to the thread pool, and how `ExecutorServices` and queues relate (programmatically). Thanks again!